# Database connection in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, database

Alright, I have done this a bunch of times on my faculty but this time I just can't make it work..
I built a simple test app and it still does not work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string _connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            string insertSql = "INSERT INTO T_TEST " +
            "(Name, Age) VALUES " +
            "('Test', 21)";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = insertSql;
                /*command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name1", "testName"));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age1", 21));*/
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Console output always returns 1. And the whole code seems like it working but when I close the program and check the DB its empty..
Yes I set the "Copy" option to "Copy if newer".
And do I need to close the connection every time I open it? Since on our faculty we didn't close it ever at all.

And can anyone explain what are .Net and vb.net? 
Thank you.

Comment: This is not pure C++, because the identifier '`public`' is not placed before function definitions.  Maybe you tagged this incorrectly?

Comment: VB.Net is a version of Visual Basic developed by Microsoft that uses the .NET framework.  The idea was to have executables written in different languages share common resources (including code), so MS created the .NET framework and created .NET versions of other languages.

Comment: What do you mean in the first comment?

Comment: I changed it. Anything related to my problem? :S

Comment: @drescherjm that's not even C++/CLI, that's C#.

Comment: Are You looking into the correct database (file)?

Comment: Soon as I used full path to DB it started working. But will it work on another PC since the path wouldn't be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code ...

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("<< Your Connection String Value >>");
    sqlcon.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcom.Connection = sqlcon;
    sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlcom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobs(JobType,JobCreation,JobStatus) VALUES (@job_type,@job_createtime,@job_iscompleted)";

    sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@job_type", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = (Int64)comboBoxJobType.SelectedIndex;
    sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@job_createtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@job_iscompleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;

    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlcom.Parameters.Clear();

    sqlcon.Close();
    sqlcom.Dispose();
```